# How to download excel in php from my sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpexcel

Hi i am trying to download excel file  in php  use Excel Report

i wrote following code

```
     $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    foreach($cusRec as $arrayValue)
                        {               
                     echo $arrayValue['branch'];
                     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0) 
                        ->setCellValue('A2',  $arrayValue['branch']);
                        $row++;
                       }         

                     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                     header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=$filename.xls");
                     header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                     $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                     $objWriter->save('php://output');
            exit;
```

data in array is in following format

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [cid] => 1 [branch] => NAGZIRI (UJJAIN) [custid] => 116018142)[1] => Array ( [cid] => 2 [branch] => NAGZIRI (UJJAIN) [custid] => 126189662 ))
```

when iterate using for loop and download file it does not show any data in downloaded  excel file .

How can i remove this error

Thanks

Comment: No data at all?!? Not even a single value in cell A2? Then check to see if any of the branch values are empty

Comment: all branch value  are no empty

Comment: Is the output actually creating an Excel file? What does MS Excel say the filetype is? If it really is an Excel file, then double check that `$cusRec` actually contains data

Comment: yes it is creating excel file and $cusRec   contain data

Comment: Then there's something very, very wrong.... the complete inability of PHPExcel to set even a basic cell value as a string is such a fundamental flaw, I think I'd have noticed it before now.... though with that echo statement in your code before saving to php://output, you're going to be downloading a corrupted file, yet you don't report that as a failure... so is that your actual code?